# In JavaScript, what is the correct `Temporal` type to use for parsing a particular string?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time, ecmascript-temporal

ECMAScript's new [`Temporal`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal) proposal defines (finally!) a modern API for handling dates and times in JS, including timezone-safe arithmetic and non-Gregorian calendars.

I know I can use ISO 8601 or RFC 3339 strings with `Temporal`. If I have string data that I want to parse into a JS date/time object, which Temporal type should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine the `Temporal` class that should be used to parse a string, it's important to pick the type whose data model matches the data in the string.

- `Temporal.Instant` represents an exact time.
  Its data model is the number of integer nanoseconds since January 1, 1970 UTC.
  This type is unaware of time zones and does not provide a way to access calendar/clock units like month or hour. It's just a timestamp.
- `Temporal.ZonedDateTime` represents an exact time from the perspective of a specific time zone.
  Its data model is a timestamp (like `Temporal.Instant`), a time zone (usually an IANA zone), and a calendar.
  The time zone is needed because this `Temporal` type (and only this type) allows DST-safe creation of derived values.
  When you add 1 day to a `Temporal.ZonedDateTime` instance, the exact time will usually be 24 hours later but it may be 23 or 25 if the addition crossed a DST transition.
- `Temporal.PlainDate` represents a timezone-less date: a local date without a time and without any reference to the time zone.
  Its data model is a year/month/day and a calendar.
- `Temporal.PlainMonthDay` represents a birthday, anniversary, or other recurring event.
  Its data model is a month, day, and calendar.
- `Temporal.PlainYearMonth` represents a month in a specific year, e.g. January 2022.
  Its data model is a year, month, and calendar.
- `Temporal.PlainTime` represents a timezone-less time of day: a local time without reference to date, time zone, or calendar.
  Its data model is an hour/minute/second, with seconds resolution down to 9 decimal digits (nanoseconds).
- `Temporal.PlainDateTime` represents a local date and time without any reference to the time zone.
  Its data model is year/month/day/hour/minute/second and a calendar.
  This type is rarely used, because the types above cover most use cases.
  If you only care about the exact timestamp and don't care about time zones, then use `Temporal.Instant`.
  If you only care about the local date, then use `Temporal.PlainDate`.
  If you care about the exact time and the time zone, then use `Temporal.ZonedDateTime`.
  Other than the few use cases detailed in the `Temporal.PlainDateTime` documentation, most of the time it's better to use a different type.
- `Temporal.Duration` represents a period of time.
  Its data model is a number of years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds, microseconds, and nanoseconds.
- `Temporal.TimeZone` represents an IANA time zone like `Asia/Tokyo` or (rarely) an offset time zone like `+06:00`.
  Its data model is the canonical ID of the time zone, e.g. `"Asia/Tokyo"` or `"+06:00"`.
- `Temporal.Calendar` represents a calendar like Hebrew, Chinese, or the default ISO 8601 calendar.
  Its data model is the ID of the calendar, e.g. `"iso8601"` or `"hebrew"`.

Note that localized string formats like `'12/25/2022'` and `'25/12/2022'` are not parseable by Temporal. Only unambiguous, computer-readable formats can be parsed by Temporal, like `'2022-12-25'`.